# Corona SDK Screen Transition Not Working on one Button

Tags: android, ios, mobile, storyboard, coronasdk

I have 3 buttons and the storyboard will only transition 2 of them. Here is my code:

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

--Forward References
local mbg
local title
local pbtn
local ibtn
local cbtn

local centerX = display.contentCenterX
local centerY = display.contentCenterY
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

function anim_pbtn(event)
    transition.to(pbtn, {time = 1000, alpha = 0, xScale = 2, yScale = .6})
    storyboard.gotoScene("game", "fade", 1000)
end

function anim_ibtn(event)
    transition.to(ibtn, {time = 1000, alpha = 0, xScale = 2, yScale = .6})
    storyboard.gotoScene("leaderboard", "fade", 1000)
end

function anim_cbtn(event)
    transition.to(cbtn, {time = 1000, alpha = 0, xScale = 2, yScale = .6})
    storyboard.gotoScene("credits", "fade", 1000)
end

function scene:createScene(event)
local screenGroup = self.view

mbg = display.newImage("mbg.png")
    screenGroup:insert(mbg)
    mbg.x = centerX
    mbg.y = centerY
    mbg.width = display.width
    mbg.height = display.height

title = display.newImage("title.png")
    screenGroup:insert(title)
    title.xScale = .7
    title.yScale = .7
    title.x = centerX

pbtn = display.newImage("play_btn.png")
    screenGroup:insert(pbtn)
    pbtn.xScale = .7
    pbtn.yScale = .7
    pbtn.x = centerX
    pbtn.y = display.contentHeight - 210

ibtn = display.newImage("ins_btn.png")
    screenGroup:insert(ibtn)
    ibtn.xScale = .7
    ibtn.yScale = .7
    ibtn.x = centerX
    ibtn.y = display.contentHeight - 130

cbtn = display.newImage("cre_btn.png")
    screenGroup:insert(cbtn)
    cbtn.xScale = .7
    cbtn.yScale = .7
    cbtn.x = centerX
    cbtn.y = display.contentHeight - 50
end

function scene:enterScene(event)
pbtn:addEventListener("tap", anim_pbtn)
ibtn:addEventListener("tap", anim_ibtn)
cbtn:addEventListener("tap", anim_cbtn)
end

function scene:exitScene(event)
pbtn:removeEventListener("tap", anim_pbtn)
ibtn:removeEventListener("tap", anim_ibtn)
end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

end



scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

What is wrong with the cbtn button and the anim_cbtn function that the screen is not transitioning? I do have a game.lua, leaderboard.lua, and a credits.lua file. I am great in java but when it comes to lua I'm just terrible. I can never find my bugs. Here is my error:

```
Runtime error
?:0: attempt to call method 'dispatchEvent' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'dispatchEvent'
?: in function 'gotoScene'
...ibrary/Application Support/Outlaw/Sandbox/6/menu.lua:27: in function                                                                                                                  <...ibrary/Application Support/Outlaw/Sandbox/6/menu.lua:25>
?: in function <?:218>
```

What Should I Do?

Comment: Check whether your `credits.lua`, and the resources used inside that class exists. Also check the case sensitivity of image names... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that, error is due to the action:

```
storyboard.gotoScene("credits", "fade", 1000)
```

So:

- Make sure that your class `credits.lua` is there in the folder where your `main.lua` exists.
- Make sure all methods and variables are correct inside your class: `credits.lua`.
- LUA is case sensitive to resources

  ie., `myImage.png` is different from `myimage.png` and `MyImage.png` and `myImage.jpg`.

So, make sure that these things are correct...

Keep coding...........

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not use "credits" (and credits.lua) as a name.  Try renaming it to gamecredits instead.  There is a core module (it's been deprecated, but apparently still causing problems) named credits.

If you still have problems after renaming it to gamecredits, then you likely have an error in that module.